# What are the advantages of mutual private set intersection methods over finding the intersection of hashed lists?

Tags: data-privacy, private-set-intersection

I can understand the usefulness of one-way private set intersection methods. Where Alice and Bob both have listed but only Alice learns the intersection of those lists while Bob learns nothing.

I don't understand the usefulness of two-way private set intersection protocols though. If Alice and Bob both learn the intersection of their lists, can't the same result be achieved by a much more simpler method of using a one way hash on the lists, exchanging them and allowing each party to compute the intersection?

What are the privacy advantages of more complicated protocols? I feel like I'm missing something simple here...

I found this related question, however, none of the answers seem to address the question of whether these more sophisticated protocols offer security advantages over the matching hashes method.
[Private set intersection, using a semi-trusted server](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/private-set-intersection-using-a-semi-trusted-server)

Answer (score 2):

**Naive hashing protocol**

Suppose Alice has items $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and Bob has items $y_1, \ldots, y_n$. In the naive hashing protocol, they agree on a common hash function $H$, and Alice sends $H(x_1), \ldots, H(x_n)$ to Bob. Bob can compute $H(y_1), \ldots, H(y_n)$ and then calculate the plaintext intersection between these two lists.

---

**Insecurity of naive hashing**

First of all, there is nothing inherently symmetric about this protocol. Bob doesn't have to *send* $H(y_1), \ldots, H(y_n)$. If he doesn't, then Alice doesn't learn anything. I think two-sided output vs one-sided output is a red herring for this question.

The naive hashing protocol is vulnerable to the following kind of attack. Suppose that after the protocol is finished Bob learns of a special value $v$ that he couldn't have predicted before the protocol (e.g., the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s are email addresses and he just learned the email address $v$ of an important person, which he didn't know before). Now Bob can test **with certainty** whether $v$ was in Alice's set, by checking whether $H(v)$ was among the values she sent. The protocol continues leaking information after it's over.

In the extreme case, the $x_i$ values can come from a small domain (e.g., phone numbers, SSNs) and Bob can simply do an exhaustive brute force attack to learn all of Alice's $x_i$'s.

---

**Difference with secure PSI**

The important property of real PSI protocols is that they prevent this kind of an attack, where one of the parties can check **after the fact** whether their opponent was holding some value. In a truly secure PSI protocol, if Bob wants to know whether Alice has an item $v$, he has to include $v$ in his set **at the time of interaction.** It should do him no good to speculate about $v$ after the protocol is finished. The PSI protocol leaks the intersection of $X \cap Y$ once, and no more information about $X$ and $Y$ is leaked thereafter.

---

**Example / better mental model for PSI**

A good way to think about PSI protocols is that they do the naive hashing protocol, except the common hash function $H$ is something that requires a secret key from both parties. Something like $H(x) = H_{\alpha,\beta}(x)$ where $\alpha$ is a key that only Alice knows and $\beta$ is a key that only Bob knows.  Since both parties contribute a secret key to the computation, you have to assume that Alice & Bob have a way of computing such an $H$ **interactively**, in a way that no one learns the inputs to $H$ -- only the outputs.

*(Note: not all PSI protocols actually work this way, but this approach is secure and it gives the right intuition about PSI security.)*

If Bob tries to do this after-the-fact attack, he will find that he can't compute $H(v)$ on his own. He doesn't have Alice's key to this $H$. This is why the computation of $H$ was interactive in the protocol. And, since the protocol has terminated, Alice will not agree to help compute $H$ on additional inputs.

Comment: I don't know why you went so far as to computing information after the protocol. Upon receiving $H(x_1),...,H(x_n)$ from Alice, Bob can brute force the possible values of $x_i$ in order to learn Alice's input. Unless the $x_i$ are guaranteed to have high entropy (which is rarely the case), this reveals everything to Bob.

Comment: True, if Bob never sends anything then there is no difference between "after the fact" and "upon receiving $H(x_i)$'s from Alice."